# Add Tap gesture on SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uikit

i wanted to know how do I add a tap gesture recognizer into an SKSpriteNode

I tried to do this on didMove method and it seems to not work

```
wayang = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "WayangPlayGuy")
        wayang.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
        wayang.position = CGPoint(x: 87, y: 101)
        let wayangTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapWayang))
        wayang.inputView?.addGestureRecognizer(wayangTap)
        //wayang.addGestureRecognizer(wayangTap)
        wayang.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        addChild(wayang)
```

Comment: `inputView` comes from `UIResponder`. That would be a custom keyboard, for example. `SKSpriteNode` is not a UIView which is why you can't add a gesture to it.

Answer (score 0):

For iOs you can take this approach in your scene `SKScene`

```swift
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        for child in children {
            if child.contains(touch.location(in: self)) {
                print(child)
                // child.somethingElse()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Similar with MacOs: (you can use extension to differentiate)

```swift
override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent)
```

And this for position

```swift
event.location(in: self)
```

Of course is highly recommended to store a reference of which objects you want to check or differentiate it for class type or even better loop over systems using ECS for a specific component.

Comment: how do i detect tap separate from drag?

Comment: You can use a logic between touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded to track the drag